# Recording info in SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a table called `dsReplicated.matDB` and a column `fee_earner`. When that column is updated, I want to record two pieces of information:

- dsReplicated.matDB.mt_code
- dsReplicated.matDB.fee_earner

from the row where `fee_earner` has been updated.

I've got the basic syntax for doing something when the column is updated but need a hand with the above to get this over the line.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dsReplicated].[tr_mfeModified] 
ON [dsReplicated].[matdb]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (UPDATE(fee_earner))
    BEGIN
        print 'Matter fee earner changed to '
    END 
END
```

Comment: Also, the UPDATE function in a trigger does not care if the value changed, only that the column is part of the update statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with triggers in SQL server is that they are called *one per SQL statement* - not once per row. So if your `UPDATE` statement updates 10 rows, your trigger is called *once*, and the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables inside the trigger each contain 10 rows of data.

In order to see if `fee_earner` has changed, I'd recommend using this approach instead of the `UPDATE()` function:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dsReplicated].[tr_mfeModified] 
ON [dsReplicated].[matdb]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- I'm just *speculating* here what you want to do with that information - adapt as needed!
    INSERT INTO dbo.AuditTable (Id, TriggerTimeStamp, Mt_Code, Old_Fee_Earner, New_Fee_Earner)
        SELECT
            i.PrimaryKey, SYSDATETIME(), i.Mt_Code, d.fee_earner, i.fee_earner
        FROM Inserted i
        -- use the two pseudo tables to detect if the column "fee_earner" has 
        -- changed with the UPDATE operation
        INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.PrimaryKey = d.PrimaryKey 
                             AND d.fee_earner <> i.fee_earner
END
```

The `Deleted` pseudo table contains the values *before* the `UPDATE` - so that's why I take the `d.fee_earner` as the value for the `Old_Fee_Earner` column in the audit table.

The `Inserted` pseudo table contains the values *after* the `UPDATE` - so that's why I take the other values from that `Inserted` pseudo-table to insert into the audit table.

Note that you really must have an **unchangeable** primary key in that table in order for this trigger to work. This is a recommended best practice for **any** data table in SQL Server anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this absolutely brilliant - in fact the concept of the Inserted and Deleted pseudo tables was entirely new to me so I didn't really understand how it was going to work until I actually gave it a try.  Really pleased with this thanks again.